# What type of Certificate do I need to create?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm creating an app for a few users, literally 5 people, that will not be distributed via the App Store.

I created an "iOS App Development" Certificate previously for local development using my personal phone and Mac (hope that was right), and now I'm ready to actually send this app to my users.

There are a lot of choices at: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/add/

Given my use case, do need to create a "Developer ID Installer" or "Developer ID Application" Certificate? Being new to native mobile development, I'm not sure which one to choose.

Frankly, I'm not even sure how to distribute the app to them yet, but I'm assuming that question probably has some overlap with the type of Certificate I need to create?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only need to add the deviceId of the other party in the certificate center to use it.

Comment: Does that mean I can use the certificate I've already created, or just modify it to add the UDIDs of the iPhones that will be installing my app? Sorry if that's an obvious question, I'm brand-new to mobile development.

Comment: Yes，just modify

Comment: Super. I have another iPhone I can try that out on. How do I distribute such an app without the app store? I can open a separate question if you'd prefer.

Comment: There are two ways to not go through the appstore, one is the enterprise certificate, and the other is the personal certificate package to generate the ipa hosting to the third party.

Comment: So it sounds like I'm doing the latter, the personal certificate, correct? I haven't delved into this too deep, but I'm assuming all I would need to send to the other users is the resulting .ipa file from my build process?

Comment: Yes, you should use a personal certificate. The maximum installed capacity of a personal certificate seems to be 100. I am not sure about this number. You can't directly give each other ipa files, you can try these platforms, [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) , [fir](https://fir.im/)

Comment: Wow, fastlane looks really cool. Thank you so much for the great information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distribute app using same "Development Certificate". You just need to add testing devices udids in device section of development portal and then include those devices in development provisioning profile of your app and replace profile with currently you are using.

I will recommend you to use "Distribution Certificate" and "Adhoc Provisioning Profile". cheers!